# Key Too Large index error when array of strings grows long

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Doing a bulk insert against a collection with documents similar to:

```
{
  "Key": "value",
  "List": ["string1", "string2", "string3" ...]
}
```

I receive "Key To Large" errors. The index was defined as:

```
db.Something.createIndex( { List: 1 } )
```

As soon as the length of the array passes the Max Key Length, it explodes. I thought, [according to the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/index-multikey/), that only an individual entry in the array could cause this error; each item in the array would be treated individually as its own key.

Am I misunderstanding? Is it the sum of the keys in the multikey index that will cause this error?

Comment: Are you sure that there aren't strings in there that are over the 1024 byte limit? I tested this in mongo 4 with an indexed document with 10K items, and it worked the way that you would expect. `const a = {list: []}; db.test_coll.createIndex({a: 1}); for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { a.list.push("string-" + i) } db.test_coll.insert(a);`

Comment: i second @willis, tested on mongo 3.6.

Comment: That's what I needed, confirmation we're morons. Thank you :)

Comment: @dansan Maybe you want to answer your own question for completeness sake?